# Difference between clock and high_resolution_clock

Tags: c++, execution-time

Is there any significant difference between these two clock functions in terms of performance and accuracy ?

```cpp
std::clock_t begin;
std::clock_t end;
double elapsedTime;
begin = clock();
// Some Function Execution
end = clock();
elapsedTime = (end - begin)*1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

```cpp
double ExecutionTime=0;
std::chrono::duration<double> total(0);
auto begin = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
// Some Function Execution
auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
total = std::chrono::duration<double>(end - begin);
ExecutionTime = total.count();
```

Comment: Apples and watermelons. `clock` measures CPU time, `std::chrono` measures wall clock time...

Comment: @rustyx, unless you do a `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>` etc, the duration depends on the clock. I've written `std::chrono` compatible clocks that counted clock cycles.